# Finding the Deadlock

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, graph-theory, decision-problem, concurrency

## Finding the Deadlock

When programming a multithreading application one must take good care to avoid deadlocking the various threads when accessing shared resources. A [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) occurs when a thread attempts to access a resource that's locked in another thread at the same time that the other thread is trying to access a resource locked by the first. This is the simple case, but it can get more complex with longer resource chains.

### The challenge

You should write a program or function that can detect a possible deadlock situation in a list of the resources accessed by each thread. This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Every thread is started at the same time, but after that they can run at any combination of interleaving. If there are 2 threads with 4 actions each, it could be run as (where each number is an action taken by the thread with that id) `1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2`, `2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1`, `1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2`, `1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1`, or any other possible combination.

### Input

You will receive, via STDIN, function parameter, or closest alternative, a list of strings. Each string will be in the format `+a` `-b`. Every one of this strings represents the locking(`+`)/unlocking(`-`) of a resource by the thread. Between every thread will be a `---` separator.
It is guaranteed that a thread won't try to lock a resource it already has locked, and that all threads will explicitly unlock all the resources they have locked before exiting.
Following is an example to demonstrate:

```
+a    # Lock resource a
+b    # Lock resource b
-a    # Unlock resource a
-b    # Unlock resource b
---   # Thread separator
+b    # Lock resource b
-b    # Unlock resource b
```

### Output

The output shall be falsy if the input doesn't contain any deadlock possibility, and truthy if it contains a possible deadlock situation. For example:

- `true`
- `false`
- `1`
- `0`

are all valid outputs, but anything clearly defined as truthy/falsy will be accepted.

### Examples

```
+a
-a
---
+a
-a
```

Output: `false`

---

```
+a
+b
-b
-a
---
+b
+a
-a
-b
```

Output `true`

Deadlock when trying to acquire `b,a` respectively for threads `1,2`

---

```
+a
+b
-a
-b
---
+a
+b
-b
-a
```

Output `false`

---

```
+a
+b
-b
-a
---
+b
+c
-c
-b
---
+c
+a
-a
-c
```

Output: `true`

Deadlock in threads 1,2,3 when trying to acquire `b,c,a` respectively.

---

http://pastebin.com/vMYRZxtW

Output `false`

---

http://pastebin.com/V5MVgNgS

Output `true`

Deadlock in threads 1,2,3 when trying to aquire `b,d,a` respectively.

---

Of course this could get a lot more complex, with more threads, more resources for each one, and so on, but I believe these tests cover the basics.

### Bonus

Since it's very very sad when you find deadlock situations when writing a program, there is a -8 byte bonus to answers outputting `:(` and `:)` as truthy/falsy respectively.

Comment: I am just assuming this, but it would be nice to clarify that the actions of each thread (starting from top of the thread) are run parallely and correspond to the same system time

Comment: The actions are run concurrently, but the time in which every action is run can't be assumed. It could occur that the threads are actually run strictly one after the other or completely interleaved. It could be that the first half of thread 1 is run, then thread 2 is run entirely, then thread 1 runs it's second half. And so on. I've updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: Ah okay, so the task is to figure out that given any possible combination of thread run times, whether a deadlock is possible.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't think that could leave doubts. Actually in the last example this is demonstrated since thread 2 doesn't try to use resource `d` until later.

Comment: Can locks/unlocks interleave in the input? E.g. `+a +b -a -b`. Your examples never contain this.

Comment: Yes, they could. Sorry, I forgot to include one that had this. I'll add one now.

Comment: @rcrmn are you sure `:)` shouldn't be for false and `:(` for true?

Comment: Yes, you are right! fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Python 2 - 227

Basically makes sure there are no loops of 'precedence'. For example in the second test, the first thread has a `a(b)` precedence and the second thread has a `b(a)` precedence.

I was thinking about rewriting this in Pyth as I think it would work well with all the itertools operations, but converting the regex will take some work so for now I'll post this and maybe try to convert it and post another answer later.

```py
from itertools import*
import re
f=lambda t:any(re.search(r"(.)((.)\3)+\1",''.join(p))for i in product(*[[m.group(1)+m.group(2)for m in re.finditer(r"(\w).*(\w).*\2.*\1",e,16)]for e in t.split('---')])for p in permutations(i))
```

Comment: This answers false to http://pastebin.com/V5MVgNgS

Comment: @Tyilo It outputs True for me; how exactly are you running it?

Comment: oh it was only reading one line for me. How are you supposed to run it?

Comment: @Tyilo I changed the format to be a function which takes a multiline string as input

Answer (score 5):

## Python - <s>586</s> <s>539</s> <s>524</s> <s>501</s> 485 bytes - 8 = 477

Indentation levels:

```
1: 1 space
2: 1 tab
3: 1 tab + 1 space
4: 2 tabs
```

--

```
import sys
V=set()
t=[[[]]]
for r in sys.stdin:
 r=r.strip()
 if'---'==r:t.append([[]])
 else:v=r[1:];V.add(v);l=t[-1][-1];t[-1].append(l+[v]if'+'==r[0]else filter(lambda x:x!=v,l))
s=lambda l:s(l[1:])+map(lambda x:(l[0],x),l[1:])if 1<len(l)else[]
E=reduce(set.union,map(lambda x:set(sum(map(s,x),[])),t),set())
for v in V:
 k=set();q=[v]
 while 0<len(q):
    u=q.pop(0)
    if u in k:continue
    k.add(u)
    for x,y in E:
     if u==x:
        if y in k:print':(';sys.exit()
        else:q.append(y)
print':)'
```

Comment: Use `;` to combine lines that are indented to save characters. Likewise, make your statements one liners.

Comment: @isaacg and ace, Thanks! I think I improved it as much as I could using your tips.

Comment: BTW if you don't mind piping the input from a file (or pressing Ctrl+D twice) then you can do `for r in sys.stdin` instead of `for r in sys.stdin.readlines()`

Comment: @ace I don't see any different behavior between using just `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdin.readlines()`, so I have changed it, thanks again.

Comment: You can remove the spaces between `print` and `':)'`